# Cannot load the stats for bootstrap-vue – please try again later

Tags: node.js, amazon-ec2, npm, npm-install, bootstrap-vue

I'm trying to use the npm to install the bootstrap-vue in my project. However, I get an error saying "[server error] Cannot load the stats for bootstrap-vue – please try again later".

I've tried to use install it manually and yarn. Neither of them work for me. The OS is ubuntu and it's running on amazon ec2.

Please help. Thanks a lot!